# convert string to ConnectionStringSettings

Tags: c#, .net

In my project I have a method which needs to return a `ConnectionStringSettings` object.  As the database and server name will change dynamically, I need to dynamically
construct the connection string.

How do I convert a `string` to `ConnectionStringSettings`?

```
public ConnectionStringSettings getConnection(string server, string database)
{
    //ConnectionStringSettings connsettings = new ConnectionStringSettings();

    string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnString"].ToString();
    connection = string.Format(connection, server, database);

    // Need to convert connection to ConnectionStringSettings
    // Return ConnectionStringSettings
}
```

--Web.config

```
<add name="myConnString" connectionString="server={0};Initial Catalog={1};uid=user1;pwd=blah; Connection Timeout = 1000"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ConnectionStringSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/999hkde5.aspx) class constructor has an overload that takes two strings (first is the name of the connection string and the second is the connection string itself).

```
public ConnectionStringSettings getConnection(string server, string database)
{
    string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnString"].ToString();
    connection = string.Format(connection, server, database);

    return new ConnectionStringSettings("myConnString", connection);
}
```

There's a [third overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19xhe2by.aspx) that takes in an extra string for the name of the provider.